# Rhino Mocks WhenCalled - Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments

Tags: rhino-mocks, rhino

WhenCalled is well documented all over the place & I'm not going into why I'm using it but  I just can't get it to work in the same way as it's detailed inpractically every post I've seen on the topic.

Basically you should be able to do something like:

```
mock.Expect(x => x. SingleOrDefault(null))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .WhenCalled(invocation => ((Action)invocation.Arguments[0]).Invoke());
```

But this doesn't compile for me - I just get an error saying Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments.

I'm using V 4.0 of Rhino Mocks - has this method changed?  I want to use 
WhenCalled to grab the arguments passed to SingleOrDefault (in this case a lambda expression).

Answer (score 1):

All answered in this blog post:

[Rhino Mocks 4.0.0](https://meisinger2.wordpress.com/tag/rhino-mocks/)

> Previously, WhenCalled allowed you to execute an Action that took, as a single parameter, a data structure encapsulating the method invocation. Since an Action was being invoked the return value of the expectation could not be changed.
>   In the current version, WhenCalled has been modified slightly to simply execute an Action
>
> In order to provide a similar feature as the original “WhenCalled”, a new method “Intercept” has been added which expects an Action that takes, as a single parameter, a data structure encapsulating the method invocation

tl;dr: Use Intercept instead of WhenCalled